# How to check light and shade of surrounding environment and the sample rate is 1000HZ

Tags: android, camera, sensors

I am trying to develop an app to check light and shade of the surrounding environment at a sample rate is 1000HZ.

I found the rate of SensorManager callback for a light sensor is too low, even when using SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST.

How can I get the light sensor value directly without SensorManager?

Is there is any other solution ? Can I use the camera to do it?

Also, does anybody know how the bytelight does it?

Comment: No phone or tablet provides sample rate beyond HD video (~60Hz). You need a (ultra) high frame rate camera, which is not for consumers and is expensive.

Comment: Alan,Thanks for your reply.Did you mean that record a HD video and we can get about 60 frame (picture) per second from the video file?

Comment: Yes. Most devices offer at least 30fps and most high end ones (HD video compatible) offer 50 to 60fps. The actual frame rate is hardware dependent. Since there is no light sensor in android, your best option is to capture frames in Camera.PreviewCallback method in real time, or extract frames from a recorded video at a later stage.

Answer (score 0):

The OS has significantly restricted the sampling rate (e.g. up to 100 Hz) because your problem is simply too energy consuming.  You may add an external PCB to do this sort of work.

Check this paper, the end of section 5.

http://conferences.sigcomm.org/hotnets/2013/papers/hotnets-final100.pdf